# General Method for Handling Fragmented input from a socket

Tags: algorithm, sockets, language-agnostic, stream

This question is a little generic, but I've found myself coming up against it in various situations over the last couple of years, so figured there must be a standard solution.

I was wondering if there were standard algorithms for handling situations whereby data is being read from some kind of socket/stream, using some kind of proprietary protocol, but messages aren't guaranteed to arrive in whole chunks?

I've come across this problem for various different protocols and various sockets/streams such as Serial Ports, TCP Sockets, UNIX sockets and currently a Bluetooth Stream in `C#`.

To illustrate this let me try to give a simple example:

```
//A simple protocol where a message starts with a #,
//ends with a *, and has the header separated with a ;
#somemessage;somedatahere* 

//A read operation on a socket may yield:
#somemessage;some  //can be truncated
#somemessage;somedatahere*#someme //can be a full message with additional bytes appended
ssage;somedatahere*#somemessage;somedatahere* //prepended bytes
```

In the past I've copied whatever's been read in into a "work buffer", and kept a track of what index I'm up to in that buffer. Then when I find a complete message I remove it from the work buffer, but I've been in the situation before whereby a load of garbage builds up at the front of the buffer.

What approaches do other people take? I'm relatively inexperienced and my background is in numerical coding where this has never been a problem before.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit too generic indeed: an answer would depend on how the protocol defines message boundaries. AFAIU, a garbage you've mentioned is really the tail portion of the previous message; it's head part has been missed somehow. In such situation you may only ignore everything until a start of next message is recognized. If the protocol doesn't clearly separate messages in the stream, usually you'd have to close a connection and start over.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process an external stream that should conform to a particular syntax, you should implement a parser that accepts that syntax, and reports syntax errors in some way. This is the case whether you are reading from a file or reading TCP/IP.

You can write the parser so it processes (accepts) one byte or character at a time. The parser will need some state variables. Some of these will be buffers.

For text streams, most syntaxes can be expressed as the arrangement of *symbols*, with the identification of individual symbols expressed using a set of rules. That naturally produces a parser divided into two parts, with one part (the *lexer*) for identifying the symbols, which it passes through to the rest of the parser.

I like to use a quasi finite-state-machine parser. In Java, the basis for that parser is  code like this:

```
 public abstract class Parser
 {

    protected abstract class State {

       public abstract State parse(char c);

       public abstract void parseEOF();

    }

    private State currentState;

    protected abstract State getStartState();

    public final void parse(char c) {
       currentState = currentState.parse(c);
    }

    public final void parseEOF() {
       currentState.parseEOF();
       currentState = null;
    }

    public final void parse(InputStream input) {
       currentState = getStartState();
       char c;
       while((c = input.read()) != -1) {
          parse(c);
       }
       parseEOF();
    }
 }
```